# Making autocomplete work with touchscreen keyboard

Tags: complete.ly

I'm using complete.ly for a site intended for use on a touchscreen.  The keyboard only appears on-screen if the selected element is a textfield or input, the code for that is:

```
if( (this.input_target.is('input') || this.input_target.is('textarea')) && this.input_target.parent().find('.popover').length == 0)
```

Is there anyway you guys can think of that I can either change the keyboard logic to include the div that complete.ly is using, or maybe change complete.ly to make this work?

I guess a better way for me to ask this would be if there is any way to detect when complete.ly's text box has focus.

Comment: If anyone needs more code to go off of, please just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the original question but I do understand your last comment:

*I guess a better way for me to ask this would be if there is any way to detect when complete.ly's text box has focus.*

well, there is a way to see when completely's text box (input type) has focus.

if you look at the documentation it says:

```
// For no-big-deal hacking
c.wrapper
c.prompt
c.input
c.hint
c.dropDown
```

so you can access the input and do something like this:

```
if (c.input.addEventListener) {
    _c.input.addEventListener("focus", yourHandlerFunction, false);
}
else {
    _c.input.attachEvent("onfocus",  yourHandlerFunction);
}
```

Comment: That looks pretty close to what I need.  I'm not sure how I would go about using that to return a boolean true if it has focus, though, which is exactly what I need.  Would it be as simple as saying something like if(c.input.onfocus){something} ?

Comment: @BammaHamma No. listen to both focus and blur events. and set a flag.
if you get a blur event you have lost focus ... if you get a focus event you have gained focus...

Comment: I see.  I'm about to get off work, but I'll try it tomorrow and see if it works.  Thank you very much, Zo, for your patience with a poor nub.